# How many pagies are necessary to open/upgrade every world?

Tags: yooka-laylee

In Yooka-Laylee, you can choose to upgrade or open every world. First open is 1, first upgrade is 3 pagies.

I guess this will scale level by level. How much do I need in pagies to open every world, and then how much to upgrade them?

Comment: Oh boy, sounds just like Banjo Kazooie.  Glad to see the developers stuck to the roots of Rare.  If I remember right, it was a fixed scale, but I don't remember how much it went up per unlock.

Comment: Havent played Banjo, but with what I know of Banjo, it's pretty much a copy paste of the Banjo games. Same kind of menus, same weird sounds during dialogue, I even heard there's a test coming!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the complete list of needed pagies to open and upgrade each world (source on the title). By the way, each world has 25 pagies to be found.

- [World 1 (Tribalstack Tropics)](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Tribalstack_Tropics)

1 pagie to open, 3 pagies to upgrade

- [World 2 (Glitterglaze Glacier)](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Glitterglaze_Glacier)

3 pagies to open, 5 pagies to upgrade

- [World 3 (Moodymaze Marsh)](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Moodymaze_Marsh)

7 pagies to open, 10 pagies to upgrade

- [World 4 (Capital Cashino)](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Capital_Cashino)

10 pagies to open, 11 pagies to upgrade

- [World 5 (Galleon Galaxy)](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Galleon_Galaxy)

12 pagies to open, 15 pagies to upgrade

Comment: There are 25 pagies in each world? That seems excessive.

Comment: that's what the sources above are stating, bottom of the summary tab, right of the page